# Dart Cross-Polymer Action Listerners

Tags: dart, actionlistener, dart-polymer

I have two dart polymer components defined: an input and a list

This looks a little something like this:

```dart
@CustomTag('input-button')
class Input extends PolymerElement {

  @observable String value = '';
  Input.created() : super.created();

  void blah(Event e, var detail, Node target) {

      someMethodCallToTheOtherObject(value);
  }
}
```

and the other element:

```dart
@CustomTag('page-content')
class PageContent extends PolymerElement {

  final List<String> values = stuff;

  PageContent.created() : super.created();

  someMethodCallListerningForEventInOtherObject(String value) {
    values.add(value);
  }
}
```

As demonstrated in the code, I'm trying to set up and ActionListerner so that when one method is "fired" in the first button object, it calls a method in the second object with given parameters.

I know this might be a little of the basic side, but I haven't see this concept really well documented anywhere. Any input you could give to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your post to include an actual question. More specific questions typically get the best answers.

Comment: It would be helpful to see how these elements are placed in your HTML.
Is one element in the ShadowDOM of the other or is one a children of the other or are they both within the ShadowDOM of another Polymer element or are they both just in the entry page HTML?

Comment: I suppose the more direct question would be: How do I handle the interaction between two instances of a polymer dart element? But thankfully, Günter, your code example was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for one element and add an event listener

```dart
(querySelector(' /deep/ page-content') as PageContent)
    .someMethodCallListerningForEventInOtherObject(value);
```

`as PageContent` is not necessary but it enables autocompletion.
You also need to import the file that contains the `PageContent` class to make this work.

or you can use an element like [core-signals](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-signals) or a number of other possible variants depending on how your elements are organized (see my comments to your question).